# Express - Router level middleware is affecting routes in other routers

Tags: node.js, express

I am building an express app in which I have multiple routers. Each router has multiple routes. There are some routes that each router that I want to protect with a middleware. There are also some routes in each router that I do not want to protect.

These are the routers defined in app.js

```
app.use('/', viewRouter)
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter)
```

These are the routes defined in viewRouter. I want to protect '/' and '/createCompany' with the 'isLoggedIn' middleware

```
router.route('/login').get(viewController.login)

router.use(authController.isLoggedIn)
router.route('/').get(viewController.getHomepage)
router.route('/createCompany').get(viewController.createCompany)
```

These are the routes defined in userRouter

```
router.route('/login').post(authController.login)
router.route('/logout').post(authController.logout)
router.route('/').post(userController.createNewUser)
router.route('/invite').post(
    authController.isLoggedIn,
    authController.restrictTo('admin'),
    authController.hasCompany,
    userController.inviteTeamMember
)
router.route('/register/:inviteToken').post(userController.register)
```

However, using `router.use(authController.isLoggedIn)` in viewRouter means that all the routes in userRouter are hitting the isLoggedIn middleware. I only want '/invite' to be protected by the isLogged in middleware. I was under the impression that using router level middleware will only affect the routes in that router but clearly this is wrong. I understand what is happening in that because the userRouter is defined after viewRouter in app.js, the isLoggedIn middleware is being hit for all the routes in userRouter, but is there any way to get around this?

I can write the route definitions like this, however I wanted to use router.use to avoid having repeat using authController.isLoggedIn every time

```
router.route('/login').get(viewController.login)
router.route('/').get(authController.isLoggedIn, viewController.getHomepage)
router.route('/createCompany').get(authController.isLoggedIn, viewController.createCompany)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grouping routes in Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894102/grouping-routes-in-express)